# AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from url but while writing on file i am getting this error where as `text` is not empty.

**my code:**

```
def gettextonly(self, url):
        url = url

        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        # kill all script and style elements
        for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id=\"bottom\" >"]):
            script.extract()    # rip it out

        text = soup.findAll(text=True)

        #print text
        fo = open('foo.txt', 'w')
        fo.seek(0, 2)
        if text:
            line =fo.writelines(text.encode('utf8'))
        fo.close()
```

Error:

```
in gettextonly
    line =fo.writelines(text.encode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 5):

`soup.findAll(text=True)` returns a `ResultSet` object which is basically a list which does not have an attribute `encode`. You either meant to use `.text` instead:

```
text = soup.text
```

Or, "join" the texts:

```
text = "".join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```